# Write Roslyn analyzer by Rider

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, analyzer, rider

Where can I find Roslyn analyzer template to use it by Rider?

There is no template in Rider as for VisualStudio mentioned at [roslyn-analyzers-docs](https://roslyn-analyzers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-start.html). Also this template is not presented in [Available templates for dotnet](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-templates-for-dotnet-new).

Comment: If you clone https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers, can you open it on Rider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it is possible to clone [Roslyn Analyzer Template](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/tree/master/samples/CSharp/Analyzers) and it can be opened in Rider.